# Match a word in pandas data frame column and return its value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames as

```
        data = {'account_name':['prepaid', 'postpaid', 'books', 'stationary','software','printer', 'mouse'], 'category':['admin','admin','admin','admin','it','it','it']}
    
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
    
        df1>        
    account_name          category
0   prepaid               admin
1   postpaid              admin
2   books                 admin
3   stationary            admin
4   software              it
5   printer               it
6   mouse                 it
    
    data2 = {'account_name':['stationary costs', 'prepaid expenses', 'postpaid expenses', 'mouse', 'software expenses']}
    
    df2 =pd.DataFrame(data2)
    
        df2>   
                account_name       
            0   stationary costs    
            1   prepaid expenses    
            2   postpaid expenses   
            3   mouse   
            4   software expenses
```

What I would like to do is partial match the `df2['account_name']` column in the `df1['account_name']` column and if there is any match in any of the words in that column then return its corresponding category in `df2`. It could be partial and full match both

```
df2>

    account_name            category
    stationary costs        admin
    prepaid expenses        admin
    postpaid expenses       admin
    dell mouse purchased    it
    software subs           it
```

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: can you provide the dfs code?

Comment: done, please check now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need mapping multiple words together is possible use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) by keys of dict and matching by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
d = df1.set_index('account_name')['category']

pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in d.keys())
df2['keyword'] = df2['account_name'].str.extract('('+pat+')', expand=False).map(d)
```

If possible split values by spaces and map each word separately use:

```
d = df1.set_index('account_name')['category']

f = lambda x: next(iter(d[y] for y in x.split() if y in d))
df2['category'] = df2['account_name'].apply(f)
print (df2)
        account_name category
0   stationary costs    admin
1   prepaid expenses    admin
2  postpaid expenses    admin
3              mouse       it
4  software expenses       it
```

Testing if return `NaN` for not matched values:

```
data = {'account_name':[ 'postpaid', 'books', 'stationary','software','printer', 'mouse'],
              'category':['admin','admin','admin','it','it','it']}
    
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)


data2 = {'account_name':['stationary costs', 'prepaid expenses',
                         'postpaid expenses', 'mouse', 'software expenses']}
    
df2 =pd.DataFrame(data2)


d = df1.set_index('account_name')['category']

pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in d.keys())
df2['keyword'] = df2['account_name'].str.extract('('+pat+')', expand=False).map(d)
print (df2)
        account_name keyword
0   stationary costs   admin
1   prepaid expenses     NaN
2  postpaid expenses   admin
3              mouse      it
4  software expenses      it
```

Comment: Any way around this error? I get this now but do not understand why
"InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects"

Comment: @PankajKaundal - can you try `d = df1.set_index('account_name')['category'].to_dict()` ?

Comment: it kinda breaks when there is a mismatch, is it possible if it returns n/a for unmatched values.

Comment: @PankajKaundal - Is possible explain more? Because tested not matched value and first solution return `NaN` for it, added to answer. There is some error?